# jQuery - combine positive selector without not() filter

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'd like to select all elements with class A and class B and **without** class C.

```
<element class="a b c">
<element class="a b">
```

If I want to select all elements with class A and class B it's simply the following:

```
$(".a.b")
```

In that case I'd get both elements from above.

But how can I include the not-selector for class C **without** using any methods like .not() or .filter()?

In that case, I'd like to get just the second element.

Comment: `$('.a.b:not(.c)')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`:not`](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector for this:

```
$(".a.b:not(.c)")
```

```js
console.log($(".a.b:not(.c)"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="a b c"></div>
<div class="a b"></div>
```